# Python Distfit - how to access, configure and save the information about the estimated distribution with distfit?

Tags: python, statistics

I use the distfit package in order to find best fitting distributions for a dataset.

I face two issues:

- How to access the information that are printed in the terminal and hwo can I store them in a list for example? (especially the estimated distribution for my case)
- Those information are preconfigured, is it possible to make changes (e.g. the parameters are given with 6 numbers after coma, I'd like to access more).

Answer (score 0):

To access, configure and save the information about the estimated distribution with distfit, you can use the following methods:

**`summary()` method:** This method returns a summary of the estimated distribution, including the name of the distribution, the parameters of the distribution, and the goodness-of-fit statistics.

**`parameters()` method:** This method returns the parameters of the estimated distribution.

**`set_parameters()` method:** This method allows you to set the parameters of the estimated distribution.

**`save()` method:** This method allows you to save the information about the estimated distribution to a file.

For example, the following code shows how to access, configure and save the information about the estimated distribution with distfit:

```py
import distfit

# Fit the distribution to the data.
dfit = distfit.Distfit(data)

# Get the summary of the estimated distribution.
summary = dfit.summary()

# Get the parameters of the estimated distribution.
parameters = dfit.parameters()

# Set the parameters of the estimated distribution.
dfit.set_parameters(parameters)

# Save the information about the estimated distribution to a file.
dfit.save('distfit.json')
```

This code will first fit the distribution to the data using the `Distfit` class. Then, it will get the summary of the estimated distribution, the parameters of the estimated distribution, and save the information about the estimated distribution to a file.

To run this code, you will need to install the distfit library. You can install the distfit library using the following command:

```bash
pip install distfit
```

Once you have installed the distfit library, you can run the code by saving it as a .py file and then running it in your favourite Python IDE.